# Mysql query to select count a column distinct?

Tags: mysql

I using MySql and I have...

```
orders
+--------+---------+-------------+
| ID     | PRO_ID  | CUS_ID      | 
+--------+---------+-------------+
| 1      | 1       | 2           |
| 2      | 1       | 79          |
| 3      | 1       | 6           |
| 4      | 2       | 41          |
| 5      | 2       | 28          |
| 6      | 2       | 33          |
| 7      | 3       | 2           |
| 8      | 4       | 9           |
| 9      | 4       | 23          |
| 10     | 5       | 43          |
| 11     | 5       | 45          |
| 12     | 5       | 78          |
| 13     | 5       | 67          |
| 14     | 6       | 12          |
| 15     | 6       | 95          |
```

How to get 5 top PRO_ID and their count. Example

```
+---------+-------------+
| PRO_ID  | COUNT       | 
+---------+-------------+
| 5       | 4           |
| 1       | 3           | 
| 2       | 3           | 
| 4       | 2           |
| 6       | 2           |
```

my **orders** table have 2 millions rows, i need a query faster. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply indexing for that particular field and go on with this query....i hope it will give you better performance

```
select PRO_ID,count(PRO_ID) as prod_count 
from orders
group by PRO_ID
order by prod_count desc 
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
select PRO_ID, COUNT(*) as total
from test 
group by PRO_ID 
ORDER BY total desc, PRO_ID
limit 5
```

here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32ee2/7)

Answer (score -1):

```
select PRO_ID,count(PRO_ID) as count 
from orders 
group by PRO_ID 
order by count desc
limit 5
```

If the query seems to slow then try adding index on your table

Comment: I think the OP needs it in the order of count.I think that is what he is trying to explain in the desired output